# NHibernate ICriteria and Expected Types

Tags: c#, nhibernate, datatable, icriteria

Is there any way to get at the types of objects I would expect NHibernate to place in an ICriteria object as the result of running a query? In this code sample, I can get at the types of my objects if they aren't null, but what if they are? Also, depending on the data returned, one "row" (object[]) may have null fields in places where other rows don't - forcing me to enumerate through all rows (worst case) to determine what each column (index of object[])  should be.

Where can I find the expected type for the object (the expected type for each of the objects in the array I've created - obviously it wouldn't be on my array, but I would expect it to be somewhere in the ICriteria hierarchy)?

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.For<MyObject>().Add(...).SetProjection(...);

IList<object[]> list = dc.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List().OfType<object[]>().ToList();

foreach(object [] o in list)
{
   foreach(object p in o)
   {
      if(p != null)
         Type t = p.GetType();
      else
         throw new ApplicationException("Query returned null for column");
   }
}
```

I ask this because having to actually examine the results returned by NHibernate seems like the wrong way to go about this. Reflection doesn't appear to be any help either, because I can't find an instance to my object's types anywhere but on the actual result "row" / "column" when examining the ICriteria object (a CriteriaImpl object) returned.

I ask because I'm trying to dynamically create a DataTable from an NHibernate result, and I want to have the columns strongly typed.

Comment: Why try to build a dataset from NHibernate ? Seems pointless , if you really need data set use plain ADO.NET

Comment: If I opt to use ADO.NET then I have to keep track of a multitude of things that I'd rather let NHibernate deal with (dialects, joining, criteria, etc. - and I'd have to parse all that text and reassemble it myself - no small task).

My problem stems from the potential for my users to add custom columns to the database and query off of them, and I'd like to be able to get the column type from NHibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types returned are the types you queried for. If your users are adding custom columns and querying freely, you won't know what you're querying for, so you can't get a strongly-typed result without inspecting the actual objects.

AFAIK this is a limitation in NHibernate.

Comment: I may be missing something, but when I use ADO.NET to run a SQL query ("SELECT Name FROM MyTable" on an example database where Name is of Type 'string'), I can get a dynamic DataTable with 1 column called 'Name' with of Type string. This column is strongly typed (DataType == typeof(string)), even if every 'Name' value returned from my query is null. No actual inspection is required.

With Hibernate, it would appear that I have to examine every result looking for the first one != null so I can get a Type from it (because NHibernate returns object Types and you can't call null.GetType()).

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the DataType property. It is a limitation in NHibernate then.